# How to change a label in only one table view cell and save it with Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm building an app that is a list of homework.

I'm a **sort** of beginner so I'm not using custom classes to save it and neither using CoreData. Just using NSUserDefaults and passing the data inside arrays between the views. My project is almost done (I want to implement some stuff like animations and etc but first I need to get it fully working right?), but I have 2 silly problems to solve, but I can't do it alone!

If I was going to put the code here the question would be too long, so I will leave the link of the project for you who is helping me check out.

https://github.com/HenriqueDoura/Agenda Here it is!

So, the *first* problem:
as it is a homework list app, it will control if the app isPendent or if it !isPendent, for that, I've put a label to the custom AtivCell called pendenciaLbl (which means pendencyLbl in English). By default, the bool is initialized as true, cause if the user is adding a homework, it is obvious that he did not finish it yet, right? 
To change the bool value to false I've added a new actionForRowAtIndexPath action, called Feito (which means Done in English). By pressing it, I make the isPendent value false. On the table view func

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

I've put an if/else statement:

```
if isPendent {
            cell.pendenciaLbl.text = "Pendente"
            cell.pendenciaLbl.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        } else {
            cell.pendenciaLbl.text = "Concluída"
            cell.pendenciaLbl.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        }
```

Pendente means Pendent and Concluída means concluded. 
The thing is that when I set the cell I'm on to Feita/Done, it is setting all the other cells as done too and changing all the pendenciaLbl.text to Concluded, which is obviously not what I want, I just want to set ONE cell as Done.

The second and last problem envolves the same boolean isPendent. I don't know how to save this value, cause if I set a cell as Done and relaunch the app (after killing it via the app switcher) the pendenciaLbl comes back to "Pendent". **How can I save the value when a cell is set to "Concluded" and check if it was set before when I launch the app?**

Sorry for all english mistakes, I'm Brazillian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you only have one variable for `isPendent`. So if one cell changes that variable, all the cells are changed.

What you'll need to do is create a `Array` of `Bools`, one for each cell. Just like you have arrays of strings for other data like `material` and `describes`.

```
var pendent = [Bool]()
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
if pendent[indexPath.row] {
    cell.pendenciaLbl.text = "Pendente"
    cell.pendenciaLbl.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
} else {
    cell.pendenciaLbl.text = "Concluída"
    cell.pendenciaLbl.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot. I didn't do exactly like that but it gave me an idea.